# DL4J Load Array of Arrays as DataSet

Tags: java, deeplearning4j

If I want to load a DataSet from an array of doubles (e.g. `{1, 2, 3, 4}` in a text file with DL4j, I use this code:

```
int numLinesToSkip = 0;
                char delimiter = ',';
                String filePath = "data.txt";
                File file = new File(filePath);
                Path path = file.toPath();
                RecordReader recordReader = new CSVRecordReader(numLinesToSkip, delimiter);
            
                recordReader.initialize(new FileSplit(file));
                int variables = 2;
                int labelIndex = 50;
                int numClasses = variables;
                int batchSize = (int) lineCount;

                DataSetIterator iterator = new RecordReaderDataSetIterator(recordReader, batchSize, labelIndex, numClasses);
                
                DataSet allData = iterator.next();
                allData.shuffle();
//DataSet is now created
```

I would like to do the same but with a 3D array of arrays, such as: `{{1, 1, 1,}{2, 2, 2}{3,4,5}{6, 6, 6}}` etc.

I can format the file however I would like. I would simply like to be able to load an array per item rather than a single double - In other words, an array of array, rather than an array of double.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DataSet can be created using 2 INDArrays as well.
If you just want to skip using CSVs and just use your own arrays, you can do something like:

```java
INDArray yourInput = Nd4j.create(double[][]);
INDArray yourLabels = Nd4j.create(double[][]);
DataSet d = new DataSet(yourInput,yourLabels);
```

Generally the abstraction you're using assumes each is a row. If you are going to be trying to do 2d, the only use case for that would be time series normally. Otherwise we enforce 1 row because it's convention to set a batch size at training/inference time. In order to work with that batch size, we can't  really allow more than 1 row. There has to be standardization somewhere in order for us to be able to perform certain tasks for you like batching.

Comment: So just to be clear, can I analyse multiple datasets to create a model? For example, if I had two sets like "player head turn speed" and "player hit position", could I create a new `Nd4j.create(double[HEAD_TURN_SPEEDS][HIT_POSITIONS]);` and be able to create a new machine learning model about that?

Comment: When you say "analyze" I assume you mean "feed to model" then yes each dataset instance is a minibatch where you would have inputs and labels as part of 1 dataset.

Comment: That is great - but how do I then use multiple INDArrays? For example if I have two pieces of data I would use `INDArray yourInput = Nd4j.create(double[1,1,1,1][2,2,2,2]);` but I can only use one INDArray to make a DataSet. So how would I do this multipled by like, 50?

Comment: You don't. You concatenate them. In deep learning most training happens with minibatches. A 1 row ndarray is a minibatch of size 1. 2 rows is a minibatch size of 2 etc.  You would do the same for your labels. In that case you can use Nd4j.concat(0,anArray) to get one array for use. One NDArray represents an infinite number of examples. Even if we allowed you to pass in a list we would still have to merge them under the hood anyways.